# Adding A Language support on My Os

Tags: language-support, support

I have a custom font in My language, I want to integrate that to the language option in Ubuntu . How could I Do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to Language icon on the up right of your desktop screen, then click on "Text Entry Setting ..." at the down right of the opening window, choose using custom font.

or

system setting> Text Entry> Using Custom Font:

Done!